# Facebook JavaScript SDK share dialog not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

Im using the FB JavaScript SDK to share some content on my website. This is the code:

```
function feedShare() {

FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'http://www.domaintoshare.com/index.html?&target=_top&output=embed&id=' + article.id,
    picture: article.picture,
    name: 'article.name',
    description: 'article.description'
}, function(response) {

}
```

});
}

I can share the article on the desktop version. If I click on the shared element on FB it redirects to the article I want to.

The problem is that it doesnt work on mobile devices. When I click on my share button the Facebook app opens and if I tap on share, the link will get broken. The parameter 'id' is no longer there, What can I do to solve this?

Comment: I think that’s not a valid URL to begin with – the query string should start with a question mark, not an ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was adding some extra info on the url that was breaking the link. This is the final code:

```
FB.ui({

    method      : 'share',
    href        : 'http://www.domaintoshare.com/index.html?id=' + article.id,
    picture     : article.picture,
    title       : article.name,
    description : article.description

}, function(response) {

}
```

It works on Android and iOs.